# How to upload Gameplay to Instagram PS4?

Tags: ps4

I've been looking round and want to creates gaming account on Instagram. But I can't seem to find a way to upload the gameplay to Instagram. I know it can be done on the Xbox one. But what about ps4? Is there something I'm missing? Help?

Answer (score 2):

On the PlayStation 4 the last 15 minutes is automatically recorded.

In order to upload this:

1. Press the *Share* button and select *Upload Video Clip*
2. Select the video clip you wish to upload
3. Select an online service to upload it to.
4. (optional) Edit the video clip
5. Select *Share*

You can upload the clip to Youtube for instance and then use that for Instagram. I don't think you can upload directly to Instagram.

[More info...](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/share/videoclip.html)

Comment: Okay awesome! How would I go about getting it off my YouTube and on Instagram? I don't know if that's your area or not.

Comment: I thought you could embed youtube videos into Instagram? Well if you can't you may wanna download the video using a youtube downloader like [this](http://deturl.com/) or [this](http://en.savefrom.net/). Once you download it, you can do anything you like with it.